# Use of <picture> inside <figure> element in HTML5?

Tags: image, html, responsive-design, w3c

In HTML5 we currently have a `<figure>` element, defined like so ([W3C reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html))

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning.

Recently a new element `<picture>` was proposed by the [Responsive Images Community group](http://www.w3.org/community/respimg/) and it was defined [in the reference](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-proposals/raw-file/tip/responsive-images/responsive-images.html#the-picture-element) like so

> The picture element used for displaying an image that can come from a range of sources (see srcset attribute). Which image the user agent displays depends on the algorithm for deriving the source image.

Since the two descriptions seems to be not contradictory (and documentation on picture is on *draft* state yet) here my question: is it possible (technically and semantically) to have a nested `picture` inside a `figure` element, in this way?

```
<figure>
   <picture>
      <source ...>
      <source ...>
      <source ...>
      <img..>
   </picture>

   <figcaption>...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I've found no references about it in specs. :\

Note: I'm aware that no browser implements currently this element, I'm just making some experiments with [jQuery picture](http://jquerypicture.com/)

Thank you.

Comment: It's just a proposal. You can't expect to find it in any specifications until it's been approved for inclusion by the HTML5 working group (whichever one it is). Perhaps a better place to ask this is in the community group's mailing list or one of the HTML5 mailing lists.

Comment: Does this even work? Never knew about `<picture>` tag

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Thanks, learnt something new ;)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - please consider re-selecting chosen answer as current is deprecated and incorrect

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You won't find it since it's not actually official yet, but I am going to assume the answer is **yes**, that is fine.

At the moment, you do something like:

```
<figure>
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="The Image">
  <figcaption>A Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and `<picture>` is simply meant to be the a method of have a multiple src'd `<img>` for responsive sites, so technically it would seem like -- if it were approved -- your example is valid.

Answer (score 101):

Mat Marquis here—I’m one of the editors on the `picture` spec ( http://picture.responsiveimages.org ).

The short answer is “yes,” the long answer is “definitely.” Semantically correct (`figure` can contain images, charts, tables, code snippets, and so on), and 100% valid.

Comment: Thanks @wilto. I see there is a great example on the Responsive Images Community Group website of using `<figure>` and `<picture>` together: http://picture.responsiveimages.org/#example-6

You should check it out @fabrizio-calderan.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you are correct in including `<picture>` in `<figure>` tag. I will substantiate this with an endorsement by Google in one of its course.

[image]

This is shown in this video

https://youtu.be/StKZMBURZpk?t=29

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, we can**. Now its official and we can use them as responsive images too.

The `<figure>` tag specifies self-contained content Ex- Images. The content of the `<figure>` element is independent of the main flow. If we removed it, it shouldn't affect the flow of the document.

The `<figcaption>` element is used to add a caption for the `<figure>` element.

```
<figure>
   <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The `<picture>` tag give more flexibility in specifying image resources. Instead of having one image, we can have multiple images that will fill the best suited Image A/Q to browser's viewport.

```
<picture>
   <source srcset="image-big.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:1920px)"> 
   <source srcset="image-med.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:1200px)"> 
   <source srcset="image-small.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:700px)"> 
   <img src="backup.png" alt="Test" class="abc">
</picture>
```

`<picture>` can also be used with `<video>` and `<audio>` elements. It will work in similar way.

**So, This is totally Valid.**

```
<figure>
   <picture>
      <source srcset="image-big.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:1920px)"> 
      <source srcset="image-med.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:1200px)"> 
      <source srcset="image-small.png" type="image/png" media="(min-width:700px)"> 
      <img src="backup.png" alt="Test" class="abc">
   </picture>
   <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4):

Figure is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#elements).
Picture is an [inline-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#elements).

Block-level elements can contain inline-level elements.
According to this and the previous answers, it's correct to place `picture` inside `figure` tag.