# Use of <picture> in <figure> element in HTML5

Tags: html, figure

```
<figure>
 <picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="img-mobile.jpg" />
  <source media="(min-width: 501px)" srcset="img.jpg" />
  <img alt="Test" src="img.jpg" />
 </picture>
</figure>
```

I looked on the internet, I couldn't find anything specific on the use of the picture element inside the figure element. [This 8-year-old publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899691/use-of-picture-inside-figure-element-in-html5) indicates that it is theoretically possible, but does not confirm.

I tried on a test site. It works, the image is well displayed.

In html5 best practice, can we use the picture element inside the figure element?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "can we use"? If you checked that already, what could be wrong in using it?

Comment: [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) is pretty much just for providing alternative img sources - is there a reason you think it should _not_ be valid? It's specifically listed as valid for figure [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content) (figure allows anything that is considered flow content)

Comment: Don't stop reading at the ticked answer. There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941403/3702797) there by one of the editors of the <picture> element which is quite clear.

Comment: I guess you know figure and picture tags are part of HTML5 semantic web design, So i guess u should use it.
more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899691/use-of-picture-inside-figure-element-in-html5

Comment: it is not a duplication because I myself quote the publication concerned. In the 8 years old publication, we talk about theory, I ask if it is confirmed 8 years later

Comment: Unless you're talking about the difference between HTML and XML/XHTML or are dealing with malformed code it is professional to use the term element as a tag is a *specific part* of an element. Additionally good to see people focused on *quality*, +1.